# How can I install Android Gradle Plugin in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to write an android app using Intellij Idea. I'd seen some tutorials and I've understood that I need to install Android Gradle Plugin. But how can I do this?

P.S. I'll be very glad if you describe it to me step by step.

P.P.S. Here are some screens below from my Intellij Idea marketplace:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgsSM.png)

UPDATE: Hello guys, I found the solution. I just reinstalled Intellij IDE and got all required plugins for android development:-)

UPDATE 2: Hello again. If you read this and can't install the android plugin, just reinstall Intellij IDE. They're bundled.

Comment: Please check that "Android" plugin is enabled in "Settings/Preferences | Plugins". Then create new project and select "Android" in wizard.

Comment: Hello. But how can i find it? I don't see something like "Android" in the marketplace(

Comment: If you use Ultimate edition then "Android" plugin is already bundled (you may check under "Installed" tab)

Comment: As you see me here, I use Community edition:)

Comment: It's bundled in Community version as well

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the Android Gradle Plugin yourself, you should instead use [`Android Studio`](https://developer.android.com/studio), the official IDE from Google for Android development.

It's based on IntelliJ but with lots of customizations and additional features. The Android Gradle Plugin already comes preinstalled and if offers great wizards to create your first app.

Once you've installed Android Studio, you can follow the [Create your first Android app Guide](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-first-app#0).

Comment: But I'd like to try it in Intellij. I'm not a professional android developer + it's a study project. Is there a way how can I do it?

Comment: "In the New Project wizard, select Android on the left." If I don't have an android icon on the left should I give up programming?)

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to create Android projects in IntelliJ. I can only recommend to install Android Studio. It's free, easy to use and just like IntelliJ :)